# How to update deeply nested object (type narrowing not working as expected, keyof compile errors)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a function to update a deeply nested object. The goal is to be able to type something like `copyWith(person, 'address' ,'street', 'zip', 98443)` to generate a copy where a deeply nested property is different than the original. I think this is the lenses feature in some functional libraries. It kind of works. See the test below. But if I add a type definition for the input object - which I like doing because it helps me ensure I'm creating a valid source object - then it no longer compiles and I don't know why. At the point in the code where I'm trying to call `copyWith`, shouldn't the type of the variable passed as input to `copyWith` be narrowed to the `signedIn` path with `custom` settings? Is there some way of getting this to work without having to explicity create  and use a type for that narrowed path?

```
it('can clone object with a deep change', () => {
  const copyWith = <
    T,
    A extends keyof T,
    B extends keyof T[A],
    C extends keyof T[A][B],
    V
  >(
    i: T,
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: C,
    value: V
  ) => ({ ...i, [a]: { ...i[a], [b]: { ...i[a][b], [c]: value } } });

  type Privacy = { mode: 'public' } | { mode: 'private' };

  type Settings =
    | { settings: 'default' }
    | { settings: 'custom'; privacy: Privacy };

  type User =
    | { state: 'unauthorized' }
    | { state: 'signedIn'; settings: Settings };

  // =========================================================
  // If add :User type definition, the test no longer compiles
  // =========================================================
  const user = {
    state: 'signedIn',
    settings: { settings: 'custom', privacy: { mode: 'private' } },
  };

  if (user.state === 'signedIn' && user.settings.settings === 'custom') {
    const copied = copyWith(user, 'settings', 'privacy', 'mode', 'public');
    assert.equal(copied.settings.privacy.mode, 'public');
  } else {
    throw new Error('This path should not have been taken.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct thinking that [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) should work here. Unfortunately [it doesn't work for nested objects](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) (hopefully yet).
You have to use top union to determine the whole type structure:

```js
const copyWith = <
    T,
    A extends keyof T,
    B extends keyof T[A],
    C extends keyof T[A][B],
    V
  >(
    i: T,
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: C,
    value: V
  ) => ({ ...i, [a]: { ...i[a], [b]: { ...i[a][b], [c]: value } } });

  type Privacy = { mode: 'public' | 'private' };

  type User =
    | { state: 'unauthorized' }
    | { 
      state: 'signedIn'; 
      settings: { settings: 'default' } 
    }
    | { 
      state: 'signedIn'; 
      settings: { settings: 'custom'; privacy: Privacy } 
    }

  // =========================================================
  // If add :User type definition, the test no longer compiles
  // =========================================================
  const user: User = {
    state: 'signedIn',
    settings: { settings: 'custom', privacy: { mode: 'private' } },
  };

  if (user.state === 'signedIn' && user.settings.settings === 'custom') {
    const copied = copyWith(user, 'settings', 'privacy', 'mode', 'public');
    assert.equal(copied.settings.privacy.mode, 'public');
  } else {
    throw new Error('This path should not have been taken.');
  }
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=23&pln=4&pc=26#code/MYewdgzgLgBKAOBPA6gSygCxgXhgHgCgZiYAVAGiJIEEYBTADyjrABMIYBrOxEAMzKUSMAEL0mLdlx78yAbWoBdISQDC45mw7deA0gsVyRyqsQBqVAHwAKUzFQAuQXYCGT6iuIAjJyM9wnVX8ANxcAGwBXOicLYgBKHEsYawBvGAA6TNRyGDkXRSc0zPTUPOVcrwKYIqyyuUqcuWAq0Mi6GABfTs64gG4CKihEeHaABQAnVFDgRBxqmABbEFZomAByeAivMNRgNZgAH3X4SdDmfY7%20weH2gFUIOnGcOyO06BdmJzWIsBcIzBAkwAXnRWBcXvM7MR3p91hBUABzMCggCSYDWvRgUJgDygUFQYAREEKOLoeIJRK%20Kz4fzCUAuWOEHQhaWxMNWa3hSNR6MxbLJ%20MJxPmuMFlPWwAi0BACwxMBOUxcMycE0VM26dmZVAA9NqcNgDYajcaTaazeaLdgdXqUQIXKxWDAHPdHjAhiMYNSCehUOAcph2sxoDAwCAYGFwAjXaAFvBUGE6BBrfrLam0%20njVRQJBYFLHk4XU9cCk7Oyvlzkaw0Wt-KKKcK3gL619JdLZTkFdNECSlisvp2PnQGR0VJcBsRUAJrHnxul2Sm4YjK9WYAAyVcwGdzptC7fkoULtatqAytYJEvCbPBhCoUFzBAodAYacPcY5Tk7ok146nJWIb9rL2Q7vps2y7Ge-TCC4ECvlA6R0AAjhE4TWDeoJ7mKEDpAOMzpEBIFbDsex9FQXR0GEDzVHYmDjCAADuIZ0AxACi4y0eM1hrKQGCoBw8AfFgEAYCAERhI6oawBgLjBO0Xh0CwbouNwYDpBBpFAA)

Also...Privacy type can be a little simpler ;)